# Higher order covariant Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

I'm in search of examples of Lagrangian, which are at least second order in the derivatives and are covariant, preferable for field theories. Up to now I could only find first-order (such at Klein-Gordon-Lagrangian) or non-covariant (e.g. KdV) ones. Also some pointers to the literature about general properties of such systems are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Klein-Gordon can be rewritten as $(\partial \phi)^2 = - \phi \Box \phi$ + boundary terms! And you can probably write many such Lagrangians yourself. Foe example, you can hit fields with powers of the Laplacian, which is covariant. Nothing prevents you from writing $\Box_x F_{\mu \nu}(x) \Box_y F^{\mu \nu}(y).$

Comment: @Vibert: Of course, I can build such a Lagrangian by myself. But I'm interested in useful ones, e.g. which describe real physical systems. E.g. general relativity is such an example, but I look for easier one.

Comment: I don't think there are many easier ones. By adding derivatives, you're raising the 'dimension' of the operator in your Lagrangian, and you lose renormalisability. This is used a lot in 'effective field theory' (with applications in flavour physics, higgs physics/EWSB etc.) but not in normal, text-book models.

Comment: There's a no-go theorem ("Ostragradski's theorem") which says higher order actions lead to unbounded energies and unstable systems, see section 2 of [arXiv:astrop-ph/0601672](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0601672) for further details on Ostragradski's theorem...

Answer (score 1):

I) As user Vibert mentions in a comment, the [Euler-Lagrange equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equations) are *not* modified$^1$ by adding total divergence terms to the Lagrangian density

$$ \tag{1}  {\cal L} ~ \longrightarrow ~{\cal L} +d_{\mu}F^{\mu}. $$

Adding total divergence terms leads to an inexhaustible source of higher-order Lagrangians.

II) Generically, without some cancellation mechanism in place [such as, that part of the Lagrangian density is (secretly) a total divergence] an $n$-order action would lead to $2n$-order Euler-Lagrange equations.

III) *Example.* The [Einstein-Hilbert (EH) Lagrangian density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action)

$$\tag{2} {\cal L}_{EH}~\sim~\sqrt{-g} \left\{g^{\mu\nu} R_{\mu\nu}(\Gamma_{LC},\partial\Gamma_{LC})-2\Lambda\right\} $$

depends on both second-order temporal and spatial derivatives of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. This is of course an important example. Here $\Gamma_{LC}$ refer to the [Levi-Civita (LC) Christoffel symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection), which in turn are first order derivatives of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. However, it is possible to add a total divergence term to render the Lagrangian density first order, as user drake mentions in a comment.
Thus the Euler-Lagrange equations for the Einstein-Hilbert action $S_{EH}[g_{\mu\nu}]$, i.e. the [Einstein field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) (EFE), are not of fourth order, as one may naively have expected, but still of second order.

IV) Higher-order Lagrangians are also discussed in many Phys.SE posts, see e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451).

--

$^1$ Note that adding total divergence terms (1) may affect consistent choices of boundary conditions for the theory.

Comment: There is no higher-order cancellation. The Einstein-Hilbert action depends on second order temporal derivatives through a boundary term, i.e., there exits an action that differs from Einstein-Hilbert's by a boundary term and that gives the Einstein equations. It is much like the Klein-Gordon Lagrangian and $\mathcal L= \phi(\partial^2-m^2)\phi$. So in regard to the question the Einstein-Hilbert action is somehow marginal.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Lagrangian for the galileon particles [for instance in this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6528). It has the property that the equations of motion remains 2nd order in the derivatives and covariant.