# Beyond the third time derivative

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

Why do texts on classical mechanics never mention any derivative of position beyond the jerk, while at the same time being general in the sense of using of generalized coordinates?

Comment: Related: [Why are there only derivatives to the first order in the Lagrangian?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/why-are-there-only-derivatives-to-the-first-order-in-the-lagrangian)

Comment: @JohnRennie that actually answers my question.

Comment: Higher order formulations have been discussed many times on Phys.SE, e.g. [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451), [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451) and links therein.