# Action for solution of general nth order differential equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, lagrangian-formalism, action

Suppose I want to find solution to a general nth order differential equation. 
(If I am right about the logic then) one might say that the solution $y\equiv y(x)$ is that function for which the following action is stationary.

$$
S=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f\ dx
$$

where function $f$ some suitable function. And $\delta S = 0$ will give the equation to be solved to find the solution.

My question is should I consider $f\equiv f(y,\dot{y},\ddot{y},...; x)$ or simply $f\equiv f(y,\dot{y}; x)$. (here $\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{dx}$)

I remember reading in *landau-lifschitz* that $q$ and $\dot{q}$ are enough to since higher derivatives depend upon them. So last one seems correct but I think nth order differential equation ought to have the $\ddot{q}$ and higher derivatives as variables.

Note I am not just looking for solution of the some physical problem but also some general mathematical problem which may not have any physical basis.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate as written, since it seems like the core of your question is why the Lagrangian doesn't include higher derivatives than $\dot{y}$. But if the other question doesn't cover what you wanted to ask, you can edit this one to explain the difference and have it reviewed for reopening. (It's a good question, just one that has come up a lot.)

Comment: Comments to the question (v1): 1. Note that _not_ all $n$th-order diff. eqs. are variational, i.e. the Euler-Lagrange eqs. of some action, cf. e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 . (In fact, that is not even the case for 2nd-order diff. eqs.) 2. Concerning the use of higher time derivatives in physics, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451 and links therein.