# Higher order Lagrangians

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

Recently I have read some papers in which the authors considered higher order lagrangians. For example, in this paper ["A path integral leading to higher-order Lagrangians" by C.Acatrinei](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.4351) the higher order Lagrangians occurs somehow naturally from the path integral approach. I am considering this as an applications to scalar field dark matter/dark energy approach and effects on holography. Are there any physical principle that limits Lagrangians only to first order?

Comment: Higher order formulations have been discussed many times on Phys.SE, e.g. [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451), [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451) and links therein.