# Why is dynamics first order in phase space?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, complex-systems

I have watched some lectures in which the lecturer said that system dynamics are (generally?) first order in phase space, forming a system of coupled differential equations. At a basic level I see this as reflecting Newton's second law $\frac{\partial ^2 x}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}/m$, however it is not at all clear to me that this is general (if it is).

Comment: Which lectures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A coupled system of [DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation)s with higher time-derivatives can be converted to a system of DEs with only first-order time derivatives by introducing more variables.
2. A [Hamiltonian formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) in a [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) is first order (i.e. contains no time derivatives of more than first order) by definition.
3. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451) related Phys.SE posts.