# Lagrangian of free particle relativistic case

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, action

Why must the covariant Lagrangian of a free particle be a first-order differential?

Comment: Related: [Why are there only derivatives to the first order in the Lagrangian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451) , [Why are differential equations for fields in physics of order two?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451) and links therein.