# Higher-order derivatives than second-order differential equations

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, differential-equations, variational-calculus, effective-field-theory

From https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2155755

> he limited himself to second-order differential equations.

> Our experience in elementary-particle physics has taught us that any term in the field equations of physics that is allowed by fundamental principles is likely to be there in the equations

I guess the author means from the effective field theory point of view. Namely, effective actions include non-renormalizable terms, which can lead to higher derivatives. I try to see an example beyond second-order differential equations.

Let me start from $\phi^4$. The effective Lagrangian is, e.g., Peskin & Schroeder eq. (12.23)
$$
\int d^d x \mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{eff}}  = \int d^d x' \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial'_{\mu}  \phi'  \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m'^2 \phi'^2 + \frac{1}{4} \left( \lambda' \phi'^4 + C \left(  \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^4 + D' \phi'^6 +\cdots \right)  \right] \tag{1}
$$

I suppose
$$
\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{eff}}  =  \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial'_{\mu}  \phi'  \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m'^2 \phi'^2 + \frac{1}{4} \left( \lambda' \phi'^4 + C \left(  \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^4 + D' \phi'^6 +\cdots \right)  \tag{2} 
$$

Try to cook a classical equation of motion. From the Euler-Lagrangian equation,
$$ 
 \frac{ \partial \mathcal{L} }{ \partial \phi}  - \partial_{\mu}  \frac{ \partial \mathcal{L} }{ \partial \left( \partial_{\mu} \phi \right) }  = 0\tag{3}
$$
plug in the effective lagrangian, we should get some extra terms than the Klein-Gordon equation
$$
\square \phi' - m^2 \phi' + C \partial'_{\mu} \left[ \left(  \partial'^{\mu} \phi' \right)  \left( \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^2     \right] +\cdots = 0.\tag{4}
$$

So far the extra term with prefactor $C$ still looks like a second-order differential equation, as one first-order derivative outside the square bracket, $\partial'_{\mu}$, acting on one first-order derivative term $\left(  \partial'^{\mu} \phi' \right)  $ times the other first-order derivative term (a first-order derivative times itself) $\left( \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^2$, i.e., $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$. If I further organize the inside square bracket part of the extra term by $f' g = （fg)' - f g' $,

$$
 C \partial'_{\mu} \left[ \left(  \partial'^{\mu} \phi' \right)  \left( \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^2     \right]  \\
\equiv C \partial'_{\mu} \left\{ \left(  \partial'^{\mu} \phi' \right)  \left( \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^2     \right\}  \\
= C \partial'_{\mu} \left\{  \partial'^{\mu} \left[   \phi' \left( \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^2  \right] -  \phi'    \partial'^{\mu}\left[ \left( \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^2 \right]  \right\}  \\
= C \underline{\partial'_{\mu}} \left\{  \partial'^{\mu} \left[   \phi' \left( \partial'_{\mu} \phi' \right)^2  \right] - 2 \phi'    \left[ \left( \partial'^{\mu} \phi' \right)   \left(  \underline{ \partial'^{\mu} \partial'_{\mu}} \phi' \right)  \right]  \right\}.\tag{5}  
$$

It seems I get a third-order differential equation from the underline part of the above equation. Is my reasoning right?

I think I did not impose any quantization in getting the equation of motion (except effective action from path integrals), since I think the view in the physics today essay is not much about quantization. Or I am not even wrong?

Or a second-order differential equation should be counted as the total number of the derivatives terms than taking a second-order differentiation on a single term?

Comment: You also get a third order term from the first term in the curly braces. The third-order terms should all cancel if you write everything out. But honestly I think it's simpler just to take the derivative directly from line 1 or line 2, rather than "further organize" things in lines 3 and 4.

Comment: Okay... then hopefully there is an example for higher-order differential equations

Comment: Sure. $(\square \phi)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OP is right that if the Lagrangian density remains of 1st order, then the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) will only be of 2nd order. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451) related Phys.SE posts.
2. However, the [Wilsonian effective action](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=wilsonian+effective+action)
   $$\begin{align}
   \exp&\left\{ -\frac{1}{\hbar}W_c[J^H,\phi_L] \right\}\cr
   ~:=~~~&\int \! {\cal D}\frac{\phi_H}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~\exp\left\{ \frac{1}{\hbar} \left(-S[\phi_L+\phi_H]+J^H_k \phi_H^k\right)\right\} \end{align}$$
   is defined by integrating out heavy/high modes $\phi^k_H$ and leaving the light/low modes $\phi^k_L$. Here $J^H_k$ denotes sources for the heavy modes. The (possibly **non-local**!) Wilsonian effective action $W_c[J^H,\phi_L]$ is the generating functional of connected $\phi_H$ Feynman diagrams in a background $J^H,\phi_L$.
3. Nevertheless, the heavy propagators are exponentially suppressed, so the **non-locality** is mild, and can be taking into account by a **Taylor expansion**, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/695184/2451).
4. The upshot is that, in the Wilsonian [renormalization group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group) flow, the Wilsonian Lagrangian density will in principle contain all possible terms that are not excluded by symmetry, e.g.
   $$ \ldots 
   + \ldots 
   +\frac{E}{2} (\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi)(\partial^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}\phi) 
   + \frac{F}{2} (\partial_{\mu}\phi)(\partial^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}\phi)(\partial_{\nu}\phi) 
   + \ldots ,$$
   i.e., the Lagrangian density becomes of **higher order**.
5. For **higher-order** Lagrangian theories,
   the EL equations (3) become
   $$ 0~\approx~\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi}
   ~=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \phi} 
   -\sum_{\mu} \frac{d}{dx^{\mu}} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\phi)} + \sum_{\mu\leq \nu} \frac{d}{dx^{\mu}} \frac{d}{dx^{\nu}} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi)} - \ldots.  $$
   Here the $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eoms, and the ellipsis $\ldots$ denotes possible higher-derivative terms.
6. In general, if the Lagrangian density is of $n$'th order, then the EL equations will be of $2n$'th order.