# Justification for the derivative expansion in the Exact Renormalization Group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, path-integral, effective-field-theory, non-locality

In the Exact Renormalization Group formalism, specifically the formalism of Wetterich, one writes down an evolution equation for the effective average action $\Gamma_k[\varphi]$, [see f.ex](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0702365v1)
$$
\partial_t\Gamma_k 
= \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr} \left[ \left( \Gamma^{(2)}_k + R_k \right)^{-1}  \partial_t R_k \right],
$$
where $R_k(q)$ is a cutoff, the trace sums over all d.o.f., $t = \ln k$ and $\Gamma^{(2)}_k$ is the second functional derivative of $\Gamma_k$.

If one does not want to do regular perturbation theory in the strength of the non-linear coupling, one needs a different expansion parameter.
A common is momentum, that is, expanding $\Gamma_k[\varphi]$ in derivatives of the field $\varphi$.
For an $\mathrm O (n)$ model, this is done by writing [(see also)](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0702365v1)
$$ 
 \Gamma_k[\varphi] = \int \mathrm d x \, 
 \left\{
  U_k(\varphi^2) + \frac 1 2 Z_k(\varphi^2) \partial_\mu \varphi_i \partial_\mu \varphi_i
 \right\}
+ \mathcal O ( \partial^4).
$$

Now, my question is, why do we only include local terms, that is, terms that can be written as a single integral over space?
Why are no terms like $\int \mathrm d x \mathrm d y \varphi_i(x) \varphi_i(y)$ necessary to include?
As Schwartz [1] reminds us, there is no guarantee that horrible non-local terms not expressable in terms of a single integrals should not appear in the effective action $\Gamma = \Gamma_{k\rightarrow0}$.
[I have seen it argued](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1366v4) that this is due to some "quasi-locality" property, however, I do not understand this, and help clarifying it would be greatly appreciated.
Is this one of those approximations where we cross our fingers and check the result afterward, or can there be given a systematic justification for it?

[1]: M.D, Schwartz, Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model, p. 736

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/694587/2451

Comment: Thanks for the link, it explains part of my question.
However, I don't see how a IR cutoff, as $k$ is, can make the high-momentum modes, which is what is integrated out, regular in momentum.
The expansion parameter is $p^2/k^2$, and $p$ is only restricted by the upper cutoff $\Lambda > k$ and thus could be much more than one.
Therefore, I this does not seem like a good expansion, yet it somehow works...

Comment: $k$ is the RG scale nothing more: it is not a cutoff of any kind. The regulator $R_k$/ regulator insertion $\partial_k R_k$ act in the appropriate limits as IR and UV regulators and furthermore lead to a focusing of modes around $p=k$. I would recommend looking up the necessary regulator properties for the Wetterich equation. I think especially the focusing around $p=k$ related to the implementation of Wilson’s RG approach in the FRG might be relevant for the question here.