# Why can't there be terms in the Lagrangian that are differentiated twice?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, action

We often say the Lagrangian is a function of some coordinates and only their first derivatives,
$$
\mathcal{L}(q,\dot{q}).
$$
Even in quantum field theory, the fields are only differentiated once,
$$
\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi).
$$
I heard Leonard Susskind mention in his lectures never to include second derivatives, and that it leads to trouble. I am just wondering why?

Comment: This is down to the so-called Ostrogradsky instability. Cf. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/57912/297348

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451 and links therein.