# Why is the Klein-Gordon equation a 2nd derivative equation?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, classical-field-theory

Note: I am not asking about why *time* is in 2nd derivative: that makes perfect intuitive sense given the relativistic need to treat space and time in equal footing.

We often hear how the Klein-Gordon is the simplest example of equation of motion in (classical/quantum) field theory. So my question is: why is ***the simplest case of equation of motion in field theory*** expressed in second derivatives, and not in first derivatives?

My first guess is that it might still be related to Lorentz invariance. Is it so, and why? Do you have physical/intuitive/geometric examples of why a first derivative Klein-Gordon equation does not work?

Comment: What you call "simplest" depends on your preferences regarding the mathematical tools you use in these equations. The Dirac equation involves only first-order derivatives and is relativistic too.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why are differential equations for fields in physics of order two?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451) and links therein.

Comment: There are [first-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) [options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rarita–Schwinger_equation), but they [introduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) [complications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor).